# Is the union of open intervals always open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the union $A:=\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{R}, x \neq0}(a_x,b_x) \cup \{x\}$, where $0\in (a_x,b_x) \: \forall x$, always open in $\mathbb{R}$?  The answer should be no, but I need help coming up with a counterexample. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of an open set?

Comment: Doesn't $A=\mathbb R$?

Comment: My understanding is that the union of an arbitrary (including infinite) number of open sets is open, and the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open, but the intersection of an infinite number of open sets is not necessarily an open set.  I am basing this on the definition that each element of an open set is an interior point such that there exists a neighborhood around the point that is completely contained by the set.

Comment: Re my previous comment, is it possible that my previous comment is relevant to the counter example that you are looking for?  One idea would be that the union of an infinite collection of closed sets might not be a closed set.  This is based on the idea that a set is closed $\iff$ the complement of the set is open.

Comment: In point set topology, open sets had the defining property as a collection containing all unions and finite intersections.

Comment: @HereToRelax For this, I'm using the characterization that a set is open if and only if its complement is closed

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, you're right. My confusion is that the complement of each set in the union is not necessarily closed, especially if x is not inside (a_x,b_x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $S_x=(a_x,b_x)\cup\{x\},\ x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then $$\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}S_x=\mathbb{R}$$  Indeed if $x\neq0$, then $x\in S_x$, and $0\in (a_x, b_x)\subset S_x\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is open in itself, then answer to the question is "yes".

Comment: Thank you for this! My confusion initially was that not all each S_x are necessarily open, hence their union may not be open. But wit your explanation I get it now: since each x is contained in S_x, which are subsets of R, and 0 is also in each S_x, taking the union over all x in R covers R.

Comment: You're welcome.  If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark, so that the question no longer shows up as unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your given sets are not open if $x \notin (a_x, b_x)$, so it's a strange question to ask, but as the other answers describe, the union is in fact open, and moreover, the union of open sets is always open (in any topological space).

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thanks for your contribution